# Boolean Check on Dictionary

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, boolean, directory

I have function that parses and looks for specific folders if they exist.

**Goal**: If these folders exist within the dictionary, I want to print them in green(folder exist) or red(folder does not exist). I'm having issues doing a boolean check on the dictionary. I'm fairly new to python.

```
def parse_directory(startpath):
for dir_path, folders, filenames in os.walk(startpath):
    path_level = dir_path.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep) 
    relative_dir = dir_path.replace(startpath, '').strip(os.sep)
    current_dir = dir_path.split(os.sep)[-1]


    if path_level == 1:
        mnemonic = relative_dir
        client_dictionary[mnemonic] = {}


        if "4x Clinic" in folders:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["clinic"] = True
        else: 
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["clinic"] = False

        if "4x Hospital" in folders:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hospital"] = True
        else: 
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hospital"] = False

        if "4x Lab" in folders:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["lab"] = True
        else:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["lab"] = False

        if "Hub Millennium" in folders:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hub_millennium"] = True
        else:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hub_millennium"] = False

        if "Client Millennium" in folders:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["client_millennium"] = True 
        else:
            client_dictionary[mnemonic]["client_millennium"] = False
```

The code above parses. Now to do the boolean check I have 2 functions, 1 to `get_status` and the other `print_colored_mnemonics` to print the mneonics(green if it exists) red(not exists).

Here is the `get_status` code:

```
def get_status(startpath):
for dict_keys, dict_values in parsing_dict.items():
    if all(dict_values):
        return True
    elif any(dict_values):
        return False
```

Here is the `print_colored_mnemonics` code:

```
def print_colored_mnemonics(startpath):

RED = "\033[91m"
RED2 = "\033[0m"
GREEN = "\033[92m"
GREEN2 = "\033[0m"

if get_status(startpath) == True:
    print(GREEN + '{}'.format(dict_keys) + GREEN2)
    if get_status(startpath) == False:
        print(RED + '{}'.format(dict_keys) + RED2)
```

Am I doing this right? I essentially want the keys of the dictionary (mnemonics) to be green if any content exists. And if the Key doesnt have any content the mnemonic should be printed in red.

Comment: So what's the problem you're actually having?

Comment: @AustinHastings code is not working properly. the code is printing all mnemonics in green, when in fact there are folders that dont hold content.

Comment: Is the first block of code supposed to be the `get_filtered_mnemonics` function?

Comment: @AustinHastings it's updated now

Comment: Okay, now what about `startpath`, `relative_dir` and `client_dictionary`? Are those all globals? Are `startpath` and `relative_dir` supposed to be the same thing? And what is `folders`?

Comment: To make your code less eyeball-searing, replace your `if/else` blocks with something like: `client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hub_millennium"] = "Hub Millennium" in folders`. The `in` operator already returns `True` or `False` o there's no reason for the `if` statement.

Comment: @AustinHastings startpath is the absolute directory to the folder path. relative_dir is the end of the absolute path if that makes sense

Comment: @FFF Yes, but I don't see any *value* being given to `relative_dir`, and I don't see any *usage* of the `startpath` parameter.

Comment: @AustinHastings Updated the first block of code hopefully that helps

Comment: That does help a bunch.

Comment: Now, what does `parse_directory` return?

Comment: @AustinHastings it    returns client_dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144002/discussion-between-austin-hastings-and-fff).

Answer (score 2):

I created a directory in my workspace called `medical`. I then created subdirectories like this:

```
medical/
    remember/
        4x Clinic
        Hub Millenium
```

I then took your code and made this script:

```
#!python3
import sys
import os

client_dictionary = {}

def parse_directory(startpath):
    print("startpath:", startpath)
    for dir_path, folders, filenames in os.walk(startpath):
        path_level = dir_path.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        relative_dir = dir_path.replace(startpath, '').strip(os.sep)
        current_dir = dir_path.split(os.sep)[-1]

        if path_level == 1:
            mnemonic = relative_dir
            client_dictionary[mnemonic] = {}

            if "4x Clinic" in folders:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["clinic"] = True
            else:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["clinic"] = False

            if "4x Hospital" in folders:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hospital"] = True
            else:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hospital"] = False

            if "4x Lab" in folders:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["lab"] = True
            else:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["lab"] = False

            if "Hub Millennium" in folders:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hub_millennium"] = True
            else:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["hub_millennium"] = False

            if "Client Millennium" in folders:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["client_millennium"] = True
            else:
                client_dictionary[mnemonic]["client_millennium"] = False


root_dir = '.' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1]
parse_directory(root_dir)
print(client_dictionary)
```

The output is this:

```
$ python test.py medical
startpath: medical
{'remember': {'hub_millennium': False, 'lab': False, 'client_millennium': False, 'hospital': False, 'clinic': True}}
```

Where `remember` would be the `mnemonic`, whatever that is, and the other stuff appears to match what your code is expecting.

Before I do anything else, I'm going to tighten up the `parse_directory` function. As @kindall pointed out, there are shorter forms that can be used. I'm also going to `mv Hub\ Millenium Hub\ Millennium` - my spelling error!

```
#!python3
import sys
import os

# If a mnemonic folder contains KEY, then it has features VALUE
FEATURES = {
    '4x Clinic' : 'clinic',
    '5x Clinic' : 'clinic', # Supports multiple values!
    '4x Hospital' : 'hospital',
    '4x Lab' : 'lab',
    'Hub Millennium' : 'hub_millennium',
    'Client Millennium': 'client_millennium',
}

def parse_directory(startpath):
    print("startpath:", startpath)

    client_dictionary = {}

    for dir_path, folders, filenames in os.walk(startpath):
        path_level = dir_path.replace(startpath, '').count(os.sep)
        relative_dir = dir_path.replace(startpath, '').strip(os.sep)
        current_dir = dir_path.split(os.sep)[-1]

        if path_level == 1:
            mnemonic = relative_dir

            # Set all features to False
            cdm = {v:False for k,v in FEATURES.items()}

            for folder,feature in FEATURES.items():
                if folder in folders:
                    cdm[feature] = True

            client_dictionary[mnemonic] = cdm

    return client_dictionary

root_dir = '.' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1]
client = parse_directory(root_dir)
print(client)
```

This produces the same output:

```
$ python test.py medical
startpath: medical
{'remember': {'clinic': True, 'client_millennium': False, 'lab': False, 'hub_millennium': True, 'hospital': False}}
```

Next, I added a new subdirectory, `medical/allfeatures`, and created all of the various subdirectories: 4x Lab, 4x Clinic, etc.

Then I added this code:

```
def get_status(mnemonic):
    """Return True if all values of mnemonic dict are true, else False"""
    return False not in mnemonic.values()

root_dir = '.' if len(sys.argv) < 2 else sys.argv[1]
client = parse_directory(root_dir)
print("Client Info:", client)
for mnemonic in client:
    print("Status of {}: {}".format(mnemonic, get_status(client[mnemonic])))
```

The output now looks like this:

```
$ python test.py medical
startpath: medical
Client Info: {'allfeatures': {'clinic': True, 'hub_millennium': True, 'hospital': True, 'lab': True, 'client_millennium': True}, 'remember': {'clinic': True, 'hub_millennium': True, 'hospital': False, 'lab': False, 'client_millennium': False}}
Status of allfeatures: True
Status of remember: False
```

I think this is what you're trying to do. If so, you can print the color using something like this:

```
if get_status(client[mnemonic]):
    color_start = GREEN
    color_end = GREEN2
else:
    color_start = RED
    color_end = RED2

print(color_start, mnemonic, color_end)
```